# Objectify entity model design

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

i am using a design model that i'm not sure is totally right so i thought maybe i should throw a question out there to find out the best approach to go about it .
I created a base entity with two fields like:

```
     public abstract  class BaseEntity
     @Index private Key<User> createdBy;
     @Index private DateTime creationDate = new DateTime();
```

Now i also have another sub class called User with its own indexes e.g :

```
     @Entity
     @Cache
     public class user extends BaseEntity
     @Index private String email ;
     @Index private String dob
```

Now when i am writing my datastore-indexes.xml file is it right to do it this way :

```
    <datastore-index kind="User"  ancestor="false" source="manual">
    <property name="createdBy" direction="asc"/>
    <property name="creationDate" direction="asc"/>
    <property name="email" direction="asc"/>
    <property name="dob" direction="asc"/>
   </datastore-index>

      or 

     <datastore-index kind="User" ancestor="false" source="manual">
    <property name="email" direction="asc"/>
    <property name="dob" direction="asc"/>
</datastore-index>
```

Thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Cloud Datastore, the indexes that you need are entirely dependent on the queries you want to run, not the data model. The [index definition](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/indexes) section in the documentation is very helpful. For example, if you wanted to run the query:

`Query<User> q = ofy().load().type(User.class)
    .filter("email", "test@example.com").order("createdDate");`

you would need the index:

`<datastore-index kind="User" ancestor="false" source="manual">
    <property name="email" direction="asc"/>
    <property name="createdDate" direction="asc"/>
</datastore-index>`

Neither of the indexes that you listed would satisfy the query (even though the properties listed in the second index is a superset of those listed in the necessary index).

You should run your application using the [App Engine development server](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/devserver) and run any queries you will need your application to run in your production service. This will automatically generate a `datastore-indexes-auto.xml` containing exactly the indexes required to serve those queries.

Comment: Thanks a lot .Figured it out after I posted the question